# YUI tooltip can't on top in JQUERY UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, tooltip, yui

I try to open a dialog use Jquery UI and draw some MS Chart. I want to use YUI tooltip to show the tooltip on MS Chart. However, this tooltip function can't on top in in this dialog. I search solution, it may need to set the "container" on YUI tooltip but I am not sure how to do it.

---

```
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 640,
            height: 'auto',
            position: [400, 110]
        });

        $(".demo a").click(function (e) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < $('area').length; i++) {

            $('area:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id', 'area-id-' + i); //change id
            $.data(this, 'area-title-' + i, $('area:eq(' + i + ')').attr('title')); //store title

            if ($.data(this, 'area-title-' + i) != undefined) {

                new YAHOO.widget.Tooltip("myTip", {
                    context: 'area-id-' + i,
                    text: "<div style=\'padding: 25px; height: 145px; width:320px; color: White; background:transparent url(Styles/black_w370_h194.png); font-family: Calibri;\'>" + $.data(this, 'area-title-' + i) + "</div>",
                    width: 300,
                    autodismissdelay: 3600000, // show one hour
                    showdelay: 0
                });
            }
```

### }

Comment: What chart is it? Because I had problems with a canvas chart that the browser not could draw over it even my dropdowns were under the canvas

Comment: it is a sample ms chart (line). i try to add a better tooltip in this chart by YUI tool. everything run fine when this chart located in <body> but when this chart on the dialog, called by JQUERY UI tool. YUI tooltip can't on top.

Comment: yes, i try z-index but fail. i think the problem in "container in YUI tooltip". i am not sure how to set this parameter.